# Shell script to show all 1 line php files

Tags: linux, bash, sh

Trying to create a shell script to search a directory recursively and display a list of all php files that only contain 1 line

I think something is wrong with my IF statement but I'm not sure

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.php
do
if [ 'find . -type f | wc -l $f == 1' ];
then echo "$f"
fi
```

Comment: yes, your test is definitely wrong, as you're testing whether the string `'find . -type f | wc -l $f == 1'` is non-empty (and, of course it's non-empty), so the test always succeeds.

Comment: maybe you'll want `if [[ $(wc -l < "$f") == 1 ]]; then echo "$f"; fi` instead.

Comment: maybe helps: `grep -c . ./**/*.php | grep ':1$'`

Comment: @jm666 Better than all answers so far!

Comment: @MarkSetchell - jm666's solution is indeed nice, but it suffers in that it will step through ALL lines of each file to count them. You could optimize nicely, as I've done in my answer using awk.

Comment: @ghoti - On a character device, it's true that reading 2 lines will be faster than reading all lines of a file. On block devices with 4k blocks, the whole block will be read regardless of the number of lines you plan to read. And if readahead is turned on, multiple adjacent blocks will be read before you need them. That makes reading only 2 lines nowhere faster than reading all lines.

Comment: @alvits - no need to post your comment in both sections of this question. I've answered your identical comment [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35304340/1072112).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will find "one-liners":

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec grep -Hcm2 $ {} + | sed -n '/:1$/{s///;p}'
```

This one will find "one-liners" which happen to have more than one line, when all the lines except one are blank:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec grep -Hcm2 '[^[:space:]]' {} + |
   sed -n '/:1$/{s///;p}'
```

The grep options `-Hcm2` mean "Always print the filename, only print the count of the matches, and match at most two lines." The pattern `$` matches any line, while the pattern `"[^[:space:]]"` matches any line containing a non-whitespace character. Ending the `-exec` with `{} +` tells `find` to provide a list of files rather than triggering the `exec` on every file, which is a lot more efficient. Finally, `sed` prints the lines which end with `:1` (after removing the `:1`), which will be the filenames of the files for which the count of lines containing a non-whitespace character was exactly one.

This is arguably more efficient than `wc` because it normally stops reading at the second line, rather than reading entire files just to check if they have more than one line.

(Also, with respect to `wc`: if the file happens to have exactly one line, but that line is not terminated with a newline character, then `wc` will report that it has 0 lines. So if you're filtering wc output for equality to 1, you may miss a few files.)

If you have a reasonably recent bash, you can avoid `find` by enabling `**` globs:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
grep -Hcm2 "[^[:space:]]" **/*.php | sed -n '/:1$/{s///;p}'
```

None of the above hacks work if you have files with newline characters in their filepaths. But you don't, right? :-)

Comment: There were a lot of great answers, but this one was the most helpful and did exactly what I wanted.

Thank you!

Comment: I do like the `grep` solution. One suggestion though, I'm pretty sure `**/*.php` will include `*.php`, so there's no need to specify both globs.

Comment: @ghoti: Apparently so. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
 for f in *.php; do awk 'END{ if(NR==1) print FILENAME}' $f; done
```

for the recursive lookup you need to use find, one alternative can be

```
 find -name *.php -print | xargs -L1 awk 'NR>1{exit} END{if(NR==1) print FILENAME}'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will search for one-line PHP files recursively:

```
find -name '*.php' -exec bash -c '[[ "$(wc -l < "$0")" -eq 1 ]] && echo "$0"' '{}' ';'
```

If you want to test for the success or failure of a command in an `if` statement, you don't use the `[` operator, but instead write it after the `if` directly:

```
if find . -type f | wc -l $f == 1; then
  echo "$f"
fi
```

However, what I wrote above still doesn't make much sense and is not what I think you intended.

The `[` itself is a command used to convert arithmetic and string comparison into an `if`-friendly form. You can combine it with output substitution (using the `$(...)` syntax) to test whether the output of a command is equal to 1.

```
if [ "$(wc -l < "$f")" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "$f"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash 4 provides the "globstar" shell option to handle your recursive requirement:

```
shopt -s globstar
wc -l **/*.php | awk '$1==1' | sed 's/^ *[0-9]* *//'
```

Or if you don't like sed, you can put more into the awk part of the pipeline:

```
wc -l **/*.php | awk '$1==1{sub(/^ *[0-9]+ */,"");print}'
```

Both of these solutions, along with (at this time) every other solution posted, suffers in that long files will be read in their entirety. You don't really need to do that -- you can skip any file if you see a second line in it.  So, again relying on Bash 4's "globstar" for recursion:

```
awk 'FNR==1{a[FILENAME]} FNR==2{delete a[FILENAME];nextfile} END{for(f in a){print f}}' **/*.php
```

Expanded for easier explanation, this is:

```
awk '
  # Upon reading the first line of a file, add its name to an array.
  FNR==1 {a[FILENAME]}

  # Upon reading the second line, delete it from the array and move on.
  FNR==2 {delete a[FILENAME];nextfile}

  # Once we've processed all files, print what's left in the array.
  END {for(f in a){print f}}
' **/*.php
```

This should read at a maximum two lines from each file. Potentially much faster than `wc -l` or `grep -c`.

Comment: On a character device, it's true that reading 2 lines will be faster than reading all lines of a file. On block devices with 4k blocks, the whole block will be read regardless of the number of lines you plan to read. And if readahead is turned on, multiple adjacent blocks will be read before you need them. That makes reading only 2 lines nowhere faster than reading all lines.

Comment: @alvits - while it's great to keep hardware in mind, sheer read speed is not the only factor when considering solutions to this question. We don't know the size of the files in question - some might be larger than 1 block. Regardless, if you compare the speed of "read a block of data and count all the newlines" versus "read a block of data and stop if you see a second newline", it's clear which should be faster. Next, we can get into the discussion of how /usr/bin/wc is compiled and whether it's faster than an interpreted language like awk...

Comment: With gawk: `FNR==2{no=1;nextfile}ENDFILE{if(!no)print(FILENAME);no=0}` should work. (And I believe my answer was available when you wrote "every other solution posted", but there are so many that it's easy to miss one.)

Comment: @rici - ah, right you are, I missed the `grep` solution at the bottom of your post. Nice one!

Answer (score 0):

With Bash 4, which has `globstar` and `readarray`, a pure Bash solution is fairly easy:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob # nocaseglob
for phpfile in **/*.php ; do
    readarray -n 2 lines < "$phpfile"
    [[ ${#lines[*]} == 1 ]] && printf '%q\n' "$phpfile"
done
```

That handles filenames with any legal characters (including newlines), and filenames that begin with dot.  It counts one-line files where the line is not terminated (unlike solutions that use `wc`).  It reads at most two lines from every file, so it shouldn't slow down a lot if it encounters many large files.  Using the `%q` format with `printf` means that the output can safely be used in shell command without additional quoting, and even files that have newlines in their names are printed on a single line.  Uncomment the `nocaseglob` to count files with suffixes such as `.PHP` or `.Php`.

Answer (score -1):

```
for FILE in $(find . -type f -name *.php)
do
  if [ $(wc -l $FILE) -eq 1 ]
  then
    echo $FILE
  fi 
done
```

Should do the trick, albeit it is a bit clunky.

By far more elegant would be

```
 find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec wc -l {} \; | egrep "^\s*1\s"
```

Comment: Consider adding double quotes around `$FILE` on line 3 in case filenames contain spaces. Also around `*.php` in first line.

Comment: Nice! you're showing lots of bad practices here: you're parsing the output of `find` and you're missing lots of quotes all over the place. And the test `[ $(wc -l $FILE) -eq 1 ]` will yield an error too.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: strictly speaking, I think he is parsing the output of `wc`. It just happens that `find` is executing the `wc` (s). But it's a matter of definition, I suppose.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf well, first of all: it works. Second, if you have a better answer, feel free to post it. Third, in general, I don't write unit tests for my shell script nor apply a style checker - for me, mission accomplished is well enough. Fourth: feel free to do sth productive and edit.

Comment: @rici: I'm talking about the first snippet, not the second one `;)`.

Comment: The only edit I would do is remove your first snippet entirely…

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf  ><(((*>, Your Royal Highness!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: right, the first one is disastrous.